# Calling .each on one element

Tags: javascript, node.js, each, node.io

I'm using `node.io` to scrape websites. Currently I'm going through [the scraping tutorial](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/wiki/Scraping).

I'm using `each` with a selector

```
$('selector').each( ... , function () { ... } );
```

However when the selector selects only one element, I am receiving this problem:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'each'
```

What might be a cause for this, and how can I mitigate this issue

Comment: What? What are you trying to do? Why are you having query selectors in node.js? This question is really not clear...

Comment: No it does not have that problem with one element, it has that problem with plain JS elements, you should be using jQuery objects containing actual DOM elements only, regardless of how many elements there are -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yqhNM/).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I use [node.io for scraping](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/wiki/Scraping), you can see this in example 3

Comment: what is `'selector'`? can you provide an actual example-value you're using?

Comment: jQuery.each() can only be called on jQuery objects.  The error message you're seeing indicates that you're tying to inoke _.each()_ on something **other than** a jQuery object.  After looking at your link, I'm confused at what you're trying to do.  The link indicates that `$` does **NOT** represent jQuery in this context.  So... I think we're both confused (since it looks like you're trying to treat `$` as if it **WAS** jQuery).

Comment: @jahroy the issue ended up being node.io using multiple selector engines that behave differently. There is an options flag that makes them behave the same. See my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at `node.io`'s source code, it appears that by default it uses `node-soupselect` and not jQuery.

Try setting:

```
this.options.expand_single_selected = false;
```

inside your job's run method. Alternatively, when you create the job, set it

```
new nodeio.Job({timeout:10,expand_single_selected:false}, methods);
```

This is checked by [these lines in the code,](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/blob/master/lib/node.io/dom.js#L30-L34) and it will enforce the correct behavior.

From `node.io`'s creator *chriso*:

> To be honest, this is a design fail on my part. I was sick of typing first() every time I wanted a single element from a collection with only one item, so I added this shortcut - I knew it would come back to bite me at some stage!

See [this project issue](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/issues/34) on how you could change it to use `jQuery` instead which will solve your issue, along with workarounds and benefits of sticking to `soupselect`.

---

According to your link, when you're using `$` you're not using jQuery, you're using [node-soupselect](https://github.com/harryf/node-soupselect).

It does not have a `.each` method.

Instead use

```
$('selector').forEach
```

Which is a native JS function

Comment: @GNi33 Yeah, I noticed it too! Maybe they were using cheerio in that example? If you check soupselect here https://github.com/harryf/node-soupselect/blob/master/lib/soupselect.js it does not appear to have a .each method

Comment: node.io seems to provide an object with a similar-to jQuery API: https://github.com/chriso/node.io/wiki/API---CSS-Selectors-and-Traversal-methods. Maybe he's just not passing the right Object to the function? The question doesn't give enough insight

Comment: @GNi33 My most educated guess is that he's doing scraping in node.js, and they offer jQuery _and_ soupselect, soupselect for node and jQuery for the browser. I'll investigate more

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum if I have two o more elements `each` work ok.

Comment: would it be possible, that he doesn't declare `$` as the second argument of the `getHTML` - callback and it's somehow still defined as the "standard" soupselect-Object then? this would be kind of weird though

Comment: that would mean that the `.each` - function is broken for that case and the answer of PSR would actually be spot on, as long as the `length` - property and `.val()` would be present

Comment: @JuanPablo If you console.log($.fn.jquery) what do you get back? (This will help verify if this is jQuery and if it is which version)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the output of `console.log($.fn.jquery)`:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/...)`

Comment: @JuanPablo Interesting, see my updated answer linking to the github issue.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum with `$.options.expand_single_selected = false;` : `TypeError: Cannot set property 'expand_single_selected' of undefined`

Comment: Right, my bad, it's not a part of $'s options, try this.options instead of $.options or when creating the job (it's the job's options), see update

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeeeeeeeeah! `this.options.expand_single_selected = false;` is the solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) For what it's worth it's really weird that you need to opt-in in order to make it consistent. I'll post an issue on their github. Update: Here, I filed an issue https://github.com/chriso/node.io/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

If you put your single element in [brackets] it will act as a single item array and get rid of this problem